# PHP function use(*) all

Tags: php, scope, anonymous-function

I often pass local variables to functions declared in variables like:

```
public function getTotal($tax)
{
    $total = 0.00;

    $callback =
        /* This line here: */
        function ($quantity, $product) use ($tax, &$total)
        {
            $pricePerItem = constant(__CLASS__ . "::PRICE_" .
                strtoupper($product));
            $total += ($pricePerItem * $quantity) * ($tax + 1.0);
        };

    array_walk($this->products, $callback);
    return round($total, 2);
}
```

Is it possible to pass every local variable that is declared in the same scope as declared function without listing them all like `use($a,$b,$c ...)`?

So if I would like like `use(*)` everything that was accessable in parent scope will be passed to declared function scope?

Comment: You use improper approach. Since you use OOP you can define needed callback as a method of the same class and then you can pass all needed data through class properties.

Comment: @hindmost I was about to suggest the same, but I realized for a local use case, such as walking an array.  The fact the method would need to be public to pass as a callback would prove to be clutter.

Comment: @Flosculus That's not right. The fact that the method only must be public if it used/called outside of its class (object). Otherwise it might have any level of visibility, i.e. it can be `protected` or even `private`.

Comment: @hindmost This is true, and very useful :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closures should be very limited in what they do.  4-5 lines tops really.

In my mind, it is far better to define the variables being made available to it as closures are essentially unstructured.

I usually inline them like this though:

```
array_walk($this->products, function ($quantity, $product) use ($tax, &$total) {

});
```

The new operation of the `use` keyword might be a bit cumbersome, but it is better than `global`.  This is a much more manageable can of worms.

Answer (score 2):

`get_defined_vars` could do the job for you

```
$a = 1;

function test ($c) {
  $b = 2;
  var_dump(get_defined_vars()); // var_dump for the generic example, adapt as you need for use
}

test(3);

// array(2) { ["c"]=> int(3) ["b"]=> int(2) }
```

You will have to use these vars from an array though.

Comment: But in another function, there will be no local variables from previous function

Comment: @Justinas OP is looking for local variables declared in the same scope, not for **all** the variables

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to list all variables, that you pass to function. You can add them to some array and pass as single argument.
But you can use [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) to get all variables, passed to function and not list all of them in function header.